Implication of Isaiah 47:2-3 “nakedness”?

Isaiah 47:1-3 “Go down, sit in the dust, Virgin Daughter Babylon; sit
on the ground without a throne, queen city of the Babylonians. No more
will you be called tender or delicate. Take millstones and grind
flour; take off your veil. Lift up your skirts, bare your legs, and
wade through the streams. Your nakedness will be exposed and your
shame uncovered. I will take vengeance; I will spare no one.”

I looked at the Interlinear text and the word for “legs” here apparently means calves as opposed to thighs. Also the word for “skirt” apparently refers to the train or hem of a robe so assumedly the idea is lifting up the skirt enough to uncover the calves but not much more than that.
With the description of nakedness being exposed I’m wondering if a woman’s calf is considered nakedness and shameful if not covered up with a full-length article of clothing or if I’m missing something here.

Welcome to BHSX - thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

It is true that woman's exposed calf was considered lewd in ancient times and still so in some eastern places.

Yes, for a woman's calf to be exposed was a shameful thing; but it depends on the circumstance. Commoners routinely exposed their calves while doing laundry in local streams but noblewomen of the city would be greatly shamed to have even their ankles exposed. Here the "woman" is Babylon. Not only is she to remove her veil (showing one's face in public was also a shameful thing for women) but she would have to hike up her dress and wade through streams. She would also be forced to grind at millstones. The image is of a formerly noble lady brought low, reduced to common labor in the countryside, a thing that wealthy city woman would find degrading in several ways. We find the metaphor carried on the the succeeding verses:

Sit silently, and go into darkness, O daughter of the Chaldeans, For
you will no longer be called The queen of kingdoms. 6 I was angry
with My people, I profaned My heritage And gave them into your hand.
You did not show mercy to them, On the aged you made your yoke very
heavy. 7 Yet you said, ‘I will be a queen forever.’ These things you
did not consider Nor remember the outcome of them.

Conclusion: The implication of "nakedness" in 47:2-3 is twofold: Babylon's sins will be exposed, and she will also suffer the ignominy of being brought low from her former position of nobility, forced to expose her calves like a common woman grinding flour and wading through streams to wash clothing.
